# Simplest GeoJSON map script

Tags: javascript, maps, geojson

I have used Polymaps in the past but can anyone point me to some really simple script that generates a map from geojson without extra bloat and library dependencies?

I have a country.json file with geojson and want to render the map without d3, openLayers, or other libraries.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you actually want to render the map or just show GeoJSON data overlaid on another map (e.g. Google maps)?

Comment: I want to show the map, sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a standalone script, but a library, but I've used [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) in the past. Pretty simple to use and works with GeoJson.

The [examples](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) on their website are pretty useful too. From their [GeoJson example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/geojson.html):

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
            layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS", 
                    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                    {layers: 'basic'} );
            map.addLayer(layer);
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
            var featurecollection = {
              "type": "FeatureCollection", 
              "features": [
                {"geometry": {
                    "type": "GeometryCollection", 
                    "geometries": [
                        {
                            "type": "LineString", 
                            "coordinates": 
                                [[11.0878902207, 45.1602390564], 
                                [15.01953125, 48.1298828125]]
                        }, 
                        {
                            "type": "Polygon", 
                            "coordinates": 
                                [[[11.0878902207, 45.1602390564], 
                                  [14.931640625, 40.9228515625], 
                                  [0.8251953125, 41.0986328125], 
                                  [7.63671875, 48.96484375], 
                                  [11.0878902207, 45.1602390564]]]
                        },
                        {
                            "type":"Point", 
                            "coordinates":[15.87646484375, 44.1748046875]
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "type": "Feature", 
                "properties": {}}
              ]
           };
           var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON();
           var vector_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(); 
           map.addLayer(vector_layer);
           vector_layer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(featurecollection));
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I have used OpenLayers as well and now looking for something simple without library dependency.